# Error deploying ASP.NET 5 Application to Heroku using dotnet-buildpack

Tags: asp.net, heroku, asp.net-core

I am attempting to deploy an ASP.NET 5 Application to Heroku using the [Heroku dotnet-buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/dotnet-buildpack). This is a brand new application created through Visual Studio 2015, I have not yet made any code modifications. While deploying, I get the error:

```
remote: Downloading dnvm as script to '/app/.dnx/dnvm'
remote:
remote: Appending source string to /app/.profile
remote: Type 'source /app/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh' to start using dnvm
remote: Architecture must be x86 or x64.
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile ASP.NET 5 app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

In my global.json I have specified the architecture as "x86".

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "runtime": "clr",
    "architecture": "x86"
  }
}
```

How can I configure my application to resolve this error?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have create a sample how to deploy ASP.NET Core WebApp on Heroku:
https://github.com/ORuban/asp.net-core_deploy_on_heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution described here https://github.com/heroku/dotnet-buildpack/issues/4. Hope this helps